# integrate tinymce into rails + backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, tinymce

I've used tinymce for quite a while. and thanks to http://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails
But now i have to include in tinymce in the app based on [backbone-on-rails](http://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails)
I've followed all the instructions for rails app.
tried to include tinymce before & after backbone files in application.js
my backbone template

```
<textarea class="tinymce" id="article_body" rows='40' cols='120' >
  <%= @article.get('body') %>  
</textarea>
```

But tinymce controlls fail to initialize.
Could you help me?

**Update 1**
I tried initing tinymce in the template & [this](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopicrphp?pid=90250#p90250):
in edit.jst.eco

```
<textarea class="tinymce" id="article_body<%= @article.get('id') %>" rows='40' cols='120' >
  <%= @article.get('body') %>
</textarea>  
<% tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", true, "article_body"+@article.get('id')%>
```

Controls o
ver texterea appear only after manual refresh (f5)

**Update 2**
I've tried adding execCommand method to the render method of the view i'm interested displaying tinymce in:

```
class Notes.Views.ArticleEdit  
  render: ->  
    $(@el).html(@template(article: @model))  
    tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", false, "article_body"+@model.get('id')  
    this
```

No changes compared with update 1
**Update 3**
tried binding of tinymce after render. used 2 approaches:
1)

```
class Notes.Views.ArticleEdit  
  render: ->  
    $(@el).html(@template(article: @model))  
    setTimeout (->
      tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", true, "article_body" + @model.get("id")
    ), 100
```

no changes. only after refresh  tinymce is shown
2) http://fahad19.tumblr.com/post/28158699664/afterrender-callback-in-backbone-js-views

```
  class Notes.Views.ArticleEdit extends Backbone.View  
  initialize: ()->  
    _.bindAll this,  "render", "afterRender"  
    _this = this  
    @render = _.wrap(@render, (render) ->  
      render()  
      _this.afterRender()  
      _this  
    )  
    @model.on('change',@render,this)  
    @model.on('destroy',@remove,this)  
  afterRender: ->  
    console.log tinyMCE  
    tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", true, "article_body" + @model.get("id")
```

Although i get a console output (proper tinymce object) i don't get tinymce :(

**Update 4**
this is project  on [github](https://github.com/Asmmund/notes/commit/d93b7e3f017271b97a8de0138330b5c6509d9d6b)

**Update 5**
*I was mistaken - item appears in DOM only afer rendered in router. so I'll have to edit Notes.Routers.Articles#edit action*

Comment: Tried to do that... update 1 & 2... no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my issue I had to edit routers action like this:

```
edit: (id)->  
    @model = @collection.get(id)  
    view = new Notes.Views.ArticleEdit(model: @model)  
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)  
    el_id = "article_body" + @model.get("id")  
    if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById(el_id)) {   
      tinyMCE.execCommand 'mceFocus', false, el_id  
      tinyMCE.execCommand "mceRemoveControl", false, el_id  
    }  
    tinyMCE.execCommand "mceAddControl", false, el_id  
    tinyMCE.triggerSave()*emphasized text
```